# Combine textbox with dropdown to make one component to either type a value or select from the dropdown list

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor, bootstrap-4

I am looking for a way to make a textbox and dropdown combine into one component where the user can either type his value or already choose from a list of existing values from a dropdown. Is there a way to do it without any autocomplete feature or comboxbox?

I am using C# ASP.NET-MVC with Razor syntax. My View looks like:

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="divGrid">
<br />
  <div class="form-group" style="padding:5px">
     <label>Page Title: </label>&nbsp;   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { @id = "pagetitle", @class = "form-control" })
   </div>
   <div class="form-group" style="padding:5px">
     <label>Page Title: </label>&nbsp;   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Title, ViewData["pageTitleList"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { @id = "pagetitle", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="padding:5px">
      <label>Page Number: </label>&nbsp;   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PageNumber, ViewData["pageNumberList"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { @id = "pagenumber", @class = "form-control" })
     </div>
     <div class="form-group" style="padding:5px">
       <label>Sequence Number: </label>&nbsp;    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Sequence, ViewData["sequenceNumberList"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { @id = "sequencenumber", @class = "form-control" })
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" style="padding:5px">
        <label>Edition Name: </label>&nbsp;    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Editionid, ViewData["editionNameList"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { @id = "editionnumber", @class = "form-control" })
       </div>
       <input type="hidden" id="pageid" value="@Model.Pageid" />
       <input type="hidden" id="pubid" value="@Model.PubId" />
</div>
```

I am looking to convert `Page Title` field into one component. Currently I have a `@TextBoxFor` that gets a value from the DB and the other component is a `@Html.DropDownListFor` that has a list of all suggested values.

My requirement is that the user can either edit the text OR select a suggested value from the dropdown list.

All the Controller methods are working fine to return the values. Any `AJAX` calls can also be incorporated as per need.

**Note:** No validation is required on the field. It can be any value which means that a user can either type what they want OR select from a suggested list of titles.

**Another Note:** The dropdown binding of Key-Value pair has only the `Text` for both attributes of the dropdown.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to achieve this requirement using `JQuery` and `CSS` styling to the respective components. So for example if you have your `TextBoxFor` and `DropDownList` for as separate components, you can refer to code below to combine them into one editable textbox with dropdown list as an option to select.

In my View, I am using a strongly typed Model binding in which `Title` is of `string` type in the model. The source for my `DropDownListFor` is coming from my Controller which can either come from database or hardcoded values. This entirely depends on your requirement. I am using `ViewData` to pass my list values from Controller to View but you can use `ViewBag` also.

```
<div class="form-group" style="padding:5px">
    <label>Page Title: </label>&nbsp;  
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Title, ViewData["pageTitleList"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { @id = "pagetitleDropwDown", @class = "editableBox" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { @id = "pagetitle", @class = "pageTitleBox",@name="pageTitleBox" })           
</div>
```

To style the above two components, you can use the following `CSS` style and tailor it to your requirement. I have tried to make it as close as possible to `form-control` class of Bootstrap elements since my other elements are using the Bootstrap classes.

```
<style>
    .editableBox {
        width: 252px !important;
        height: 40px !important;
        border-radius: 4px !important;
        border-color: #CCC !important;   
    }

    .pageTitleBox {
        width: 231px !important;
        margin-left: -255px !important;
        height: 35px !important;
        border: none !important;
        padding: 6px 12px;
    }
</style>
```

Now, coming to the `JQuery` part, you would first have to assign the `html` for your textbox to selected value of dropdown list which is `onchange` event. Once that is done, the other part is simply getting the value of the assigned id to the textbox and then using that value as per requirement. This value can either be a selected value from dropdown list or something the user has entered in the textbox.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){       
      $(".editableBox").change(function(){         
        $(".pageTitleBox").val($(".editableBox option:selected").html());
      });    
     });

     if ($("#pagetitle").val() == "") {
        alert("Please enter page title!");
        return false;
     }
     else
     {
      var pagetitle = $("#pagetitle").val();
      alert("You have selected or entered: " +pagetitle);
      //Use AJAX to send it to the server or do what you require
     }  

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you're describing seems to be exactly what a combobox does.

If you need this functionality purely on the client side, you could make one using javascript (using a div / ul > li panel and a textbox) yourself or you could look into a webcomponent based combobox.

Maybe the [vaadin components combobox](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-combo-box) would be a usefull alternative.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was able to get this done by using plain Javascript with CSS tweaks. I will post my solution shortly.